# Qt QML for Beaglebone Black

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qml, beagleboneblack, debian-based

I am want to make a Qt Quick application with Python and use it on BeagleBone Black. I am using Debian on the board. As a newbie to the board I dont find article on internet very helpful to me. I will be really thankful for a easy and quick guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made my QtQuick application run on a Beaglebone Black and AI. I've done it with C++, but probably my process helps you even though. I didn't cross compile, but I've built it on the Beaglebone itself. That was easier for me, since I had several issues with cross compiling.

1. update your BBB

1.1 sudo apt-get update

1.2 sudo apt-get upgrade

2. install x-window and GUI on BBB (https://aruljohn.com/blog/xwindow/)

2.1. apt-get install x-window-system

2.2 sudo apt-get install xfce4

3. install OpenGL (https://medium.com/geekculture/a-beginners-guide-to-setup-opengl-in-linux-debian-2bfe02ccd1e)

just follow these instructions. Installing GLFW befor the make i had to install:

- sudo apt install libxinerama-dev
- sudo apt install libxcursor-dev
- sudo apt install libxi-dev

4. install your needed Qt libraries

4.1 apt-get install libqt5qml5 qml-module-qtquick-controls qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev

5. if not yet done: sudo startx to start GUI desktop
6. optional: to test Qt and EGLFS (https://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoneBlack/SGX_%2B_Qt_EGLFS_%2B_Weston)

6.1 apt-get install qtquickcontrols5-examples

6.2 cd /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/examples/quickcontrols/extras/dashboard

6.3 sudo qmake

6.4 sudo make

6.5 export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs

6.6 export QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=none

6.7 ./dashboard

Now you should see the dashboard opened on your screen.

7. send your Qt project to your BBB

7.1 sudo rsync -avz /home/sivo/desktop/Benchmark_Suite (or whatever your folder and project is called)

7.2 debian@192.168.178.129:/home/debian/Benchmark_Suite

7.3 qmake

7.4 make

7.5 ./Benchmark_Suite

That worked well for me. Hope for you as well. BTW: My Qt project was developed in Qt 5.15.

Good luck!